# How to insert into an existing temp table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I am trying to execute two select statements into a query that pumps data into a temp table. The first query will have 5 columns while the second query will have only one column.

The first can be achieved by:

```
Select a.ID AS [a], 
       b.ID AS [b], 
       c.ID AS [c]
INTO #testingTemp
FROM
....
```

Now I have my second query trying to pump data into `#testingTemp`:

```
Select z.ID AS [c]
INTO #testingTemp
FROM
....
```

But my problem is `There is already an object named #testingTemp in the database`?

I tried to search for a solution on the Internet but mostly people are only facing the problem at my first part but apparently nobody trying to expand a temp table on second query?

Comment: is there anything that makes you to insert values into temp table only using 'select into' method.?

Comment: "Select Into" select from one table and insert into a nother CREATING it. You cant use "select into" on already existing table

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Change it into a insert into statement. Otherwise you create the same temp table multiple times and that is not allowed.

```
Insert into #testingTemp (a,b,c)
Select a.ID AS [a], 
       b.ID AS [b], 
       c.ID AS [c]
FROM
```

Answer (score 6):

The second query should just be a normal insert.

```
    INSERT INTO #testingTemp
    (a,
     b,
     c)
   select etc.
```

dont forget to drop the temptable when you are done.

Answer (score 4):

And if you want to insert everything:

```
INSERT INTO #TempTableName
SELECT * FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP table #GTable
DECLARE @GTable TABLE (GID varchar(50))
DECLARE @GUIDs varchar(1000) 
SET @GUIDs = '6FD866AF-84D6-47A4-9C4E-F20B3F885B09,B645BAA4-DD0A-452A-9720-47F72B7FFB74,C4CE530A-930A-41A2-B451-941052D39CC5'
--SELECT  data FROM dbo.Split(@GUIDs,',')  
SELECT data into #GTable FROM dbo.Split(@GUIDs,',')  

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[tblLocations] 
WHERE [LocationGUID]in (select * from #GTable)
```